# Layout temporal nodes along x-axis

Tags: d3.js

I have written a small piece of code ([Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v1x8r932/)) where each dot represent a data point in x-axis. The location in x-axis is calculated based on the date+time. The problem is the way the dots are distributed in x-axis: a large space remains unused, and the dots occludes with each other. Although the spatial position is important just to show their relative time, however, the exact distance is not important here. Can you please suggest me any solution or algorithm how to handle this problem?

```
var graphData = [
    {
        session: 1,
        children: [
            {id: 11, time: "2015-12-18 15:00:00", adjList: [{id: 21, w: 0.5}, {id: 24, w: 0.8}]},
            {id: 12, time: "2015-12-18 15:01:32", adjList: []},
            {id: 13, time: "2015-12-18 15:03:40", adjList: [{id: 32, w: 0.4}]},
            {id: 14, time: "2015-12-18 15:05:04", adjList: []}]
    },
    {
        session: 2,
        children: [
            {id: 21, time: "2015-12-18 08:55:00", adjList: []},
            {id: 22, time: "2015-12-18 08:59:10", adjList: [{id: 14, w: 0.6}]},
            {id: 23, time: "2015-12-18 09:02:00", adjList: [{id: 11, w: 0.2}]},
            {id: 24, time: "2015-12-18 09:06:45", adjList: [{id: 32, w: 0.7}]}]
    },
    {
        session: 3,
        children: [
            {id: 31, time: "2015-12-18 08:40:50", adjList: []},
            {id: 32, time: "2015-12-18 08:43:00", adjList: [{id: 24, w: 0.1}, {id: 13, w: 0.3}]}]
    },
    {
        session: 4,
        children: [
            {id: 41, time: "2015-12-18 16:00:00", adjList: [{id: 31, w: 0.01}]},
            {id: 42, time: "2015-12-18 16:09:12", adjList: [{id: 31, w: 0.15}]},
            {id: 43, time: "2015-12-18 16:09:55", adjList: [{id: 22, w: 0.95}]}]
    },
];


/*
 * SVG
 */
var margin = {top: 50, right: 50, bottom: 50, left: 50},
    width = 1000 + margin.left + margin.right,
    height = 200 + margin.top + margin.bottom,
    xPos = 500, yPos = 100;

var svg = d3.select("#fcgraph")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("x", xPos)
    .attr("y", yPos)
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);
var svgGroup = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + 10 + "," + height / 2 + ")");


/*
 * Scale
 */
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").parse;
var times = [];

graphData.forEach(function (d, i) {
    d.children.forEach(function (c, i) {
        times.push(parseDate(c.time));
    })
})

var x = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0, width]);

x.domain(d3.extent(times, function(d) {
    return d;
}));

// calc pos in x axis
var nodes = [];
graphData.forEach(function (d, i) {
    var session = d.session;
    d.children.forEach(function (c, i) {
        nodes.push({id: c.id, 
                    session: session, 
                    pos: {x: x(parseDate(c.time)), y: 50}
                   });
    }) // foreach
}) // foreach


/*
 * Draw the nodes.
 */

var nodeColor = d3.scale.category10();

var circle = svgGroup.selectAll(".circle")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "circle");

circle.append("circle")
    .attr("cx", function (d) {
        return d.pos.x;
    })
    .attr("cy", function (d) {
        return d.pos.y;
    })
    .attr("r", 10)
    .style("fill", function (d) {
        return nodeColor(d.session);
    })
    .append("title").text(function (d) {
        return d.id;
    });

// Label
circle.append("text")
    .attr("x", function (d) {
        return d.pos.x;
    })
    .attr("y", function (d) {
        return d.pos.y;
    })
    .attr("font-size", "10px")
    .attr("fill", "white")
    .text(function (d) {
        return d.id;
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could play around with using a poly-linear (or a poly time scale).

Simply construct a new, poly time scale:

```
var xMod = x.copy().range([0,width/4,width/2,width]);

xMod.domain([
    parseDate("2015-12-18 08:40:50"),
    parseDate("2015-12-18 10:00:00"),
    parseDate("2015-12-18 15:05:04"),
    parseDate("2015-12-18 16:09:55"),
     ]);
```

And, use this to map the values instead of x.

Source :

http://bl.ocks.org/herrstucki/5403383